# What are "System32\config\systemprofile\javaXX.log" files in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, java

I have Windows server whose `c:\` drive is almost full. Only 2 GB is free instead of 60 GB, on which size of folder `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile` is 24.1 GB. Folder is showing me two kind of files, `javaxx.log` and `javaxx.log.lck`. where `xx` is two digit number.

My questions are:

- What data is contained by this folder?
- Can we delete data from the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%systemroot%\System32\config\systemprofile` is the `%USERPROFILE%` equivalent for the system user `nt authority\system`: e.g. if you run command line as the system user, `cd %AppData%` will change to directory `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming`.

The `javaXX.log` files are probably generated by some Java program using [`FileHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) (from [`java.util.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)) with default settings or default log rotation pattern. Shortened, relevant parts:

> By default each `FileHandler` is initialized using the following
>   `LogManager` configuration properties where `<handler-name>` refers to the
>   fully-qualified class name of the handler. If properties are not
>   defined (or have invalid values) then the specified default values are
>   used.
>
> - `<handler-name>.pattern` specifies a pattern for generating the output file name. See below for details. (Defaults to
>     `%h/java%u.log`).
>
> A pattern consists of a string that includes the following special components that will be replaced at runtime:
>
> - `%h` the value of the `user.home` system property
> - `%g` the generation number to distinguish rotated logs
> - `%u` a unique number to resolve conflicts
>
> Generation numbers follow the sequence 0, 1, 2, etc.

The `user.home` would be `%USERPROFILE%` in Windows, so this would results in the naming pattern of your `.log` files. The `.lck` files are just lock files to prevent simultaneous usage of these files.

We can't say how important these log files are for you. You could create an automated script that removes the oldest log files, or even better implement this to the log rotation in the Java program.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response, your detailed answer was very helpful to understand.